# $scope.$watch isn't firing after load in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using angular.js and am trying to use $watch to fire a function when my variable changes. It fires when the data is initially loaded, but not after. I'm not sure exactly what is going on here?

Code is pasted below:

```
function gradeChart($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('studentData.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.students = data;
   });

    $scope.$watch('students',function(change){
       console.log('this fires on load but not after');
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the request been successfully executed? Try to add an error function or monitore the request using chrome or firebug to see if the request really was successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code runs "after" and updates `$scope.students`.

However, here are the two most common problems related to updating $scope arrays:

1. If you reassign `$scope.students` to a new array, the $watch may still be looking at the previous array (reference).  Try using `angular.copy()` in your "after" code:
   `angular.copy(data, $scope.students);`
2. If you are changing one of the elements of the array, you'll need to use either [$watchCollection](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) (if it is available in the version of Angular you are using) or check for object equality instead of reference (note 3rd parameter):
   `$scope.$watch('students',function(change){...}, true);`